# Error of file not found while running a program in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, file-not-found

****while running a program in Visual Studio 2010 I got an error Written "Unable to start program c:\users.........  system cannot find specific file."*** 
Please tell me solution of it*

Comment: While running which program? The program you are just writing? Which program name is given in the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your shortcut  points to nowhere or you didnot install VS 2010 properly. reinstall it and try to open in Program Files folder.